# insert items into array using graphql - Parse server

Tags: parse-platform, graphql, parse-server

I have a class that contains a field called 'notes'. Its data type is array. In the mutation, I'm able to save data on the field. problem is it overwrites the value. I want to add value in the array. how do I do it? here's my mutation. I know I'm not doing the right thing, but can't find it in the documentation as well

```
mutation {
  updateParcel(input: { id: "B6aESEwWcA", fields: { notes: ["wow"]}}) {
    parcel {
      objectId
      notes {
        ... on Element {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: of course, it's a resolver responsibility

Comment: @xadm, yes but how do I write the mutation?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no operation implement to add elements on array yet. Would you mind to open an issue to the open source repo?

Comment: **not a matter of mutation syntax!!!** update logic (implemented in resolver) usually replaces passed fields ... write **custom logic in resolver** or pass entire, updated dataset (previous+new)